# How to factor out and cut off a parameter

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation, algebraic-manipulation

In an exemplary expression

```
expr = -6 3^(1/3) c1 kL^4 L^2 (δ^3/L^3)^(1/3)
```

all parameters are real, especially `L > 0`. `FullSimplify[]` with the assumption `L > 0`

```
FullSimplify[ expr, L > 0]
```

cancels out the parameter `L`.

How can I force *Mathematica* to do this simplification inside a function?

```
sol = {w ->Function[{x}, -6 3^(1/3) c1 kL^4 L^2 (δ^3/L^3)^(1/3)
                    BesselI[1/3, (2 (-kL^2 L)^(3/2))/(3 L^(3/2) δ^3)] Gamma[4/3] ]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. The example I gave was to easy... Please look at my edit.

Comment: "the parameter L in the argument can be cut" - what does this mean? If you meant that the `L^(3/2)` in the numerator and denominator should cancel out, then @Artes's suggestion works.

Comment: In your revised example you left out the assumption `L > 0`, i.e., the second argument to `FullSimplify`. Although `Simplify` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected my input.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry for my wording and thanks for your hint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function) is [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll), so you need to work around that. Here is one method:

```
Activate @ Simplify[Inactivate[Evaluate @ sol, Function], L>0]
```

> {w -> Function[{x}, -6 3^(1/3) c1 kL^4 L (δ^3)^(1/3)
>        BesselI[1/3, (2 (-kL^2)^(3/2))/(3 δ^3)] Gamma[4/3]]}

Answer (score 1):

```
FullSimplify[
BesselJ[-(1/
3), (2 (kL^2 L + L \[Delta]^3)^(3/2))/(3 L^(3/
2) \[Delta]^3)] Gamma[
2/3] HypergeometricPFQ[{2/3}, {4/3, 
5/3}, -((kL^2 L + (L - x) \[Delta]^3)^3/(9 L^3 \[Delta]^6))], 
Assumptions -> {L \[Element] Reals, L > 0, 
k \[Element] Reals, \[Delta] \[Element] Reals, 
kL \[Element] Reals}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)

```
sol = {w -> 
    Function[{x}, -6 3^(1/3) c1 kL^4 L^2 (\[Delta]^3/L^3)^(1/
         3) BesselI[
       1/3, (2 (-kL^2 L)^(3/2))/(3 L^(3/2) \[Delta]^3)] Gamma[4/3]]};

ReplacePart[sol, {1, -1, -1} -> Simplify[sol[[1, -1, -1]], L > 0]]

(* {w -> Function[{x}, -6 3^(1/3) c1 kL^4 L (\[Delta]^3)^(1/3)
     BesselI[1/3, (2 (-kL^2)^(3/2))/(3 \[Delta]^3)] Gamma[4/3]]} *)
```